# Insert keyframe on an object's custom property with Python

Tags: python, scripting

How can I add keyframes to custom properties with python?  Usually, I can use the function

```
object.keyframe_insert(data_path="location")
```

but I couldn't find the right data_path of a custom property.

Comment: Thanks ideasman42, it works perfectly. Never used StackExchenge and it is difficult for me to not at least thank you for your efficient help. But I didn't found where is the best place to put this thanks...

Comment: You can thank ideasman42 by accepting the answer. Just click the 'v' and it turns green :)

Comment: you are right, it's done.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Keyframes on custom properties use Python's getitem/setitem syntax rather then getattr/setattr.

This matches python api, where you would access `object.location` as an attribute and `object["prop"]` for a custom property.

So you would need to write it like this:

```
object.keyframe_insert(data_path='["prop"]')
```

Note that you have to use `"` quotes, not `'`,
`'["prop"]'` can be written as `"[\"prop\"]"` too of course.

I think we have this documented, I'll have to double check though.