# Add keyframe to a scene property

Tags: python, scripting

Using Python to add a keyframe to an object seems easy (see [here](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_63_5/info_quickstart.html#animation) or [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3014/1112)), but how can I add a keyframe to a scene property?

As a concrete example, take `bpy.context.scene.gravity`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even though the examples linked are to keyframe an object, there is in fact no difference and the same methods apply to both.

Simple:

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.keyframe_insert(data_path="gravity", frame=10.0)
```

Advanced:

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
if not scene.animation_data:
    scene.animation_data_create()
if not scene.animation_data.action:
    scene.animation_data.action = bpy.data.actions.new("GravityAction")

fcurve = None
for fcurve in scene.animation_data.action.fcurves:
    if fcurve.data_path == "gravity":
        break
if not fcurve or fcurve.data_path != "gravity":
    fcurve = scene.animation_data.action.fcurves.new("gravity")
keyframe = fcurve.keyframe_points.insert(frame=10.0, value=20.0)
keyframe.interpolation = "LINEAR"
#keyframe.handle_left
#keyframe.handle_right
```