# How do I add a keyframe for a certain channel using Python?

Tags: python, scripting

If I want to add a keyframe in the graph editor, I know I can do this:

```
bpy.ops.graph.keyframe_insert(type='ALL')
```

And I suppose that if I change the 'ALL' to 'SEL', it will only apply to the selected channel, but if I want a script that changes multiple channels in different ways, how can I select them with python?

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7127/2271) and these paragraphs 
[#1](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_0/info_quickstart.html#animation), 
[#2](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_0/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html?highlight=keyframe_insert#bpy.types.bpy_struct.keyframe_insert),
[#3](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_0/bpy.types.Keyframe.html#bpy.types.Keyframe),
[#4](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_0/bpy.types.FCurve.html?highlight=keyframe_points#bpy.types.FCurve.keyframe_points)
in the docs for api methods/functions to create/manipulate channels.

You might define your own function:

```
def get_channel(action, data_path, index=0):
    for fcurve in action.fcurves:
        if fcurve.data_path == data_path and fcurve.array_index == index:
            return fcurve
    #nothing found
    return None

action = bpy.data.actions['CubeAction']
data_path = "location"
index = 2

fcurve = get_channel(action, data_path, index)
```

In [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9368/2271) some options are given to find out the `data_path` of a channel.

To select an fcurve in the UI you simply set its [`select`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_0/bpy.types.FCurve.html?highlight=fcurve#bpy.types.FCurve.select) property to `True`.