# keyframe_insert from data.layers

Tags: python, scripting, keyframes

actualy I know how to insert the keyframe to custom properties; that was solved in [previous post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3013/insert-keyframe-on-an-objects-custom-property-with-python)

with the same idea I want to insert the keyframe to **object.data.layers**

I can access and modify the data layers values:

```
context = bpy.context 
obj= context.active_object
obj.data.layers[0]
```

I test some ideas in order to insert the keyframe with any result:

```
obj.data.keyframe_insert(data_path = 'layers[\"1"\]')
obj.data.keyframe_insert(data_path = layers[str(1)]))
obj.data.keyframe_insert(data_path = '"layers[1]"')
obj.data.keyframe_insert(data_path = 'layers[1]')
obj.data.keyframe_insert(data_path = layers[1])
```

at this point I think in the wrong place

**some ideas please**

****************************** update 1***********
I have this layers as buttons in a addon UI
[image]

[image]

after insert
[image]

Comment: @batFINGER  I have this layers as buttons in a addon UI, and I can add that using "i"

Comment: Yeah sorry about that `C.object.data.keyframe_insert('layers', frame=20, index=2)`   Really the same as key-framing a single location axis.

Comment: @batFINGER  that is the answer!!! thanks!!